# Phaser3: Shader with microphone input (Web)

Tags: javascript, shader, phaser-framework

I want to do an audio input vizualizer with Phaser 3, I’m trying to get the mic input to a shader but I can’t find a way to make it work.

I have a basic understanding on shaders and I can work with textures that are images but I really don’t understand how to provide a sound. I checked a working example made in three.js: [three.js webaudio - visualizer](https://threejs.org/examples/webaudio_visualizer) and I already managed to get the sound input from the microphone as an Uint8Array of 1024 numbers.

Here’s the shader I’m using:

```js
// simplesound.gsl.js
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

precision mediump float;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

varying vec2 fragCoord;

void main() {
  vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
  vec2 mu = texture2D(iChannel0, uv).rg;

  float y = uv.y - mu.x;
  y = smoothstep(0., 0.02, abs(y - 0.1));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(y);
}
```

And here's my scene code, trying to make it work:

```js
import Phaser from 'phaser';
// This will provide the array mentioned above with code that will use `navigator.getUserMedia`.
import { setupAudioContext } from '../audiostream';

export default class MainScene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'MainScene2' });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.glsl('simplesound', '/static/simplesound.glsl.js');
  }

  create() {
    this.shader = this.add.shader('simplesound', 400, 300, 800, 600);

    // When the user presses the 'g' key we will start listening for mic input
    const GKey = this.input.keyboard.addKey('G');

    GKey.on('down', () => {
      setupAudioContext((array) => {
        // this array is the array mentioned above, in the three.js example they do something like creating
        // a texture from this input and providing that texture to the shader uniform. I tried different things but
        // nothing worked :(
        //
        // I tried using this.shader.setChannel0 and this.shader.setUniform but nothing seems to work as well.
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I've been trying to make this work for a while, but couldn't get anything :(

Comment: I have a bit oftopic question, is the shader really needed? I myself an interested in seeing here a solution, but would a pure Javascript and phaser solution(without a shader), be helpful?

Comment: Well not really, I was trying with a shader but would be happy if anyone could provid a pure JS solution

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, I hope my answer could help you, with your phaser-project. :)

Comment: Just so that you know I found, out how the audio visualisation can work with the shader, I posted a new answer, with the details, if you are still interessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a possible solution **without shaders**, by using only using phaser and javascript could look like this *(really **no shader**, but I'm also really interested in how a shader version, would look like)*.

In this demo I'm using data from an audio file. *So that it works for your UseCase, you just would have to plug the microphone data into the `data` variable.*

**Demo:**
*(comments in the code, are made to highlight the main idea)*
Click and wait some seconds. **btw.:** I added some screenshake, to give the demo more juice.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
    
    var data = [];
    var playing =  -1;
    var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    var buffer;
    var source;
    var url = 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/audio/Rossini - William Tell Overture (8 Bits Version)/left.ogg'

    // START Audio part for Demo
    function loadAudio() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        request.onload = function() {
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buf) {
                buffer = buf;
                playAudio();
            });
        };
        request.send();
    }
    
    function playAudio() {
        source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
        source.connect(analyser);
        source.start(0);
    }

    // END Audio part for Demo

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 536,
        height: 183,
        scene: {
            create,
            update
        },
        banner: false
    }; 

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    // this would be the varibale that should be updated from the audio source
    var markers;
    var createRandomData = true;

    function create () {
        // Start create Marker texture 
        // this could be remove if you want to load an actual image
        let g = this.make.graphics({x: 0, y: 0, add: false});
        
        g.lineStyle(10, 0xffffff);
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0, 0);
        g.lineTo(50, 0);

        g.strokePath();

        g.generateTexture('marker', 30, 10);
        // End create Marker texture 
    
        // Create the markers
        // the repeat property sets how many markers you want to display, if you want all 1024 => that would be your value
        markers = this.add.group({ key: 'marker', repeat: 50,
            setXY: { x: 10, y: 10, stepX: 35 }, setOrigin: { x: 0, y: 0}});
        
        this.add.rectangle(10, 10, 180, 20, 0).setOrigin(0);
        let label = this.add.text( 10, 10, 'Click to start music', {color: 'red', fontSize:'20px', fontStyle:'bold'} )
        
        // start and stop the playback of music     
        this.input.on('pointerdown', function () {
            switch (playing) {
                case -1:
                    loadAudio();
                    playing = 1;
                    label.setText('Click to stop music');
                    break;
                case 0:
                    playAudio();
                    playing = 1;
                    label.setText('Click to stop music');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    source.stop();
                    playing = 0;
                    label.setText('Click to start music');
                    break;
            }   
        }); 

    }

    function update(){
        if (markers){
            // here we update the y-position of the marker in depending on the value of the data. 
            // ( min y = 10 and max y ~ 245)
            markers.children.iterate(function (child, idx) {
                child.y = 10 + (config.height - 20) / 255 * data[idx];
                
                // you could even add some camera shake, for more effect
                if(idx < 3 && data[idx] > 253){
                    this.cameras.main.shake(30);
                }
            }, this);
            
            // if the analyser is valid and updates the data variable
            // this part could some where else, I just wanted to keep the code concise
            if(analyser){
              var spectrums = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
              analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrums);

              // convert data to a plain array and updating the data variable
              data = [].slice.call(spectrums);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> Basically this application *"only"* alters the Y-positions of each marker, based on the value returned from the audio array, which is loaded from the audio file.
> ***Disclaimer:** this is rough demo code, and could use some cleanup/improvement, if it should be used in production.*

Answer (score 2):

**This is a working solution, using the mentioned shader, through  phaser**

After a short *deep-dive* into ***glsl*** and after starting to understand  shader's and the surrounding concepts, I found out how shader work's with phaser (atleast for this task), it is actually pretty elegant and straightforward, how it was implemented.

**Basically** you *"just"* would need to:

1. load the shader in `preload`

   ```
   this.load.glsl('simplesound', 'simplesound.glsl.js');
   ```
2. add the shader to the `scene`, in the `create` function for example

   ```
    this.shader = this.add.shader('simplesound', x, y, width, height);
   ```
3. create two texture to pass to the shader (so that you can swap them), in the `create` function
   *(becarful to select a texture size that respects the **power-of-two** size)*

   ```
    this.g = this.make.graphics({ x: 0, y: 0, add: false });
    this.g.generateTexture('tex0', 64, 64);
    this.g.generateTexture('tex1', 64, 64);
   ```
4. In the `update` function, create a texture that represents the ***audio data***

   ```
    ...
    var spectrums = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrums);
    data = [].slice.call(spectrums);
    ...
    let g = this.make.graphics({add:false});
    data.forEach( (value, idx ) => {
        g.fillStyle(value <<16 );
        g.fillRect(idx * 10, 0, 10, value);
    });
   ```
5. and at last update the *next* texture, and pass new texture-key of the newly recreated texture to the `shader`

   ```
    if(this.shader.getUniform('iChannel0').textureKey == 'tex0'){
        this.textures.remove('tex1');
        g.generateTexture('tex1', 64, 64);
        this.shader.setChannel0('tex1');
    } else {
        this.textures.remove('tex0');
        g.generateTexture('tex0', 64, 64);
        this.shader.setChannel0('tex0');
    }
   ```

> Ofcourse this code could be optimizied with functions, better variable and texture-key naming, but this is left to the reader.

**Small working Demo:**
*(uses audio file, instead of mic, and is based on the code of my previous answer)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

const TEXTURE_SIZE = 128;

const glslScript = `#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

precision mediump float;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

varying vec2 fragCoord;

void main() {
  vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
  vec2 mu = texture2D(iChannel0, uv).rg;

  float y = uv.y - mu.x;
  y = smoothstep(0., 0.02, abs(y - 0.1));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(y);
}`;

var playing = -1;
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
var source;
var url = 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/audio/Rossini - William Tell Overture (8 Bits Version)/left.ogg'

// START Audio part for Demo
function loadAudio() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function () {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buf) {
            playAudio(buf);
        });
    };
    request.send();
}

function playAudio(buffer) {
    source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.connect(analyser);
    source.start(0);
}

// END Audio part for Demo
var config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function create() {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to start and stop the music')
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(1000)
        .setFontFamily('Arial');
        
    this.add.rectangle(0, 0, config.width, 40, 0xffffff)
        .setDepth(999)
        .setOrigin(0);

    var baseShader = new Phaser.Display.BaseShader('shader', glslScript);

    this.shader = this.add.shader(baseShader, 0, 10, config.width, config.height - 10)
        .setOrigin(0);

    // start and stop the playback of music     
    this.input.on('pointerdown', function () {
        switch (playing) {
            case -1:
                loadAudio();
                playing = 1;
                break;
            case 0:
                playAudio();
                playing = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                source.stop();
                playing = 0;
                break;
        }
    });
}

function update() {

    if (analyser) {
        var spectrums = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrums);

        let data = [].slice.call(spectrums);

        let g = this.make.graphics({ add: false });
        data.forEach((value, idx) => {
            g.fillStyle(value << 16);
            g.fillRect(idx * 10, 0, 10, value);
        });
        
        let textureName = this.shader.getUniform('iChannel0').textureKey == 'tex0' ? 'tex1' : 'tex0';
        
        if(this.textures.exists(textureName)){
            this.textures.remove(textureName);
        }
        g.generateTexture(textureName, TEXTURE_SIZE, TEXTURE_SIZE);
        this.shader.setChannel0(textureName);
      
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```